# Regular expression [^A-J] and match result

Tags: javascript, regex

Could you please explain, why output result of next match is `s`?

**Update**: I thought that output should be `I` as matched in regular range character.

```js
var str = "Is this enough?";
var patt1 = new RegExp("[^A-J]");
var result = str.match(patt1); // ["s", index: 1, input: "Is this enought?"]
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<p id="id"></p>
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you *expected* the result to be; as it is, nobody knows what it is that you think requires explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression matches any character outside the range of upper-case `A` through upper-case `J`, and so `s` is the first character that meets that requirement. A regular expression like yours will match anywhere in the search string.

To be more clear, the `^` at the start of your character group expression means that the group should include all characters *not* described by the contents of the `[^ ]`.  Your range is `A-J`, so `[^A-J]` matches all characters *except* `A` through `J`.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about matching outside range

Comment: @FSou1 I don't understand what you mean. What did you expect the pattern to match?

Comment: I have no idea why do you reply about 'matching any character outside the range'. Looks like that's because there is `^`

Comment: @FSou1 yes, that is exactly what that leading `^` means. If you want to match `A` through `J`, leave off the `^`.

Answer (score 1):

`^` means "match the char that is not in the set of the following characters". Because you haven't specified any flags, it returns only the first match. The first match is `s`, which is not in the set of characters A to J.

Comment: Doesn't `^` means to match any character in set at start of the string?

Comment: Not inside a character class it doesn't

Comment: @FSou1 no - the `^` has two different roles in regular expressions. When it's at the start of a `[ ]` group, it means to match the complement of that group. You're thinking of `^` at the start of a pattern *outside* `[ ]`.

Comment: Looks like i confuse `/^A/` and `/[^A]/`